# date between not working if date spans multiple years

Tags: php, mysql

Alright I have a script (this is broken up)

```
$monday = date('m/d/y',strtotime('this week monday'));
$this_monday = date('y-m-d',strtotime('this week monday'));
$tuesday = date('m/d/y',strtotime('this week tuesday'));
$this_tuesday = date('y-m-d',strtotime('this week tuesday'));
$wednesday = date('m/d/y',strtotime('this week wednesday'));
$this_wednesday = date('y-m-d',strtotime('this week wednesday'));
$thursday = date('m/d/y',strtotime('this week thursday'));
$this_thursday = date('y-m-d',strtotime('this week thursday'));
$friday = date('m/d/y',strtotime('this week friday'));
$this_friday = date('y-m-d',strtotime('this week friday'));
$saturday = date('m/d/y',strtotime('this week saturday'));
$this_saturday = date('y-m-d',strtotime('this week saturday'));
$sunday = date('m/d/y',strtotime('this week sunday'));
$this_sunday = date('y-m-d',strtotime('this week sunday'));

$fourth_monday = date('m/d/y',strtotime($this_monday.'+21 days'));
$fourth_tuesday = date('m/d/y',strtotime($this_tuesday.'+21 days'));
$fourth_wednesday = date('m/d/y',strtotime($this_wednesday.'+21 days'));
$fourth_thursday = date('m/d/y',strtotime($this_thursday.'+21 days'));
$fourth_friday = date('m/d/y',strtotime($this_friday.'+21 days'));
$fourth_saturday = date('m/d/y',strtotime($this_saturday.'+21 days'));
$fourth_sunday = date('m/d/y',strtotime($this_sunday.'+21 days'));


$fourthSchedule = DB::getInstance()->getAssoc("SELECT * FROM sched WHERE full_name = ? AND date between ? and ?", array(
        $tech, $fourth_monday, $fourth_sunday));
    foreach($fourthSchedule->results() as $results) {
        $sched_rows_4[$tech][] = $results;
    }
```

This works great if it stays in the current year. The problem is, that if that week (like it will this year), spans between the end of December and the beginning of January, it wont return results.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Is your `date` field in the database of the `Date` type ?

Comment: It is not its a varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your answer to my remark, the answer is then easy :

In the alphabetical order, 01-01-2014 comes before 12-31-2013, so your comparison results (`between`, `<` or `>` ) will always be quite erratic. This appears more obviously when passing from a year to another, but could happen also within the same year depending on your current date format...  (here in Belgium the standard is `dd-mm-yyyy` , so 15-12-2013 would come before 21-01-2013 , for example...)

EDIT (added details from remark) :

The best solution Would be to use a date type field. If you really wish to use varchar, use a date format in which alphabetical order is respected : yyyy-mm-dd

In both cases, you will need to run a query to update your currently existing data. To convert to DateTime format, create a DataTime field and update it by casting the value from your current varchar field. If you keep the varchar type, then simply update the field using string manipulation to order the date values as needed.

Don't forget to do a backup before manipulating anything of course :-)

Comment: Alright so right now I have close to 100,000 entries using the current date format. Is there a way to maintain that format but still use the alphabetical ordering like you mentioned?

Comment: Just convert the field either to a date-time field (really the best idea, why store dates in a varchar anyway ?) or transform the data to match `yyyymmdd` format. A last alternative could be to do the casting within each query, but that would be much slower so you really don't want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This may helpfull

```
<?php

//this is current day
$from_here_to = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

$monday = date('m/d/y',strtotime('this week monday', $from_here_to));

echo $monday.'<br/>';

//change your year 
$from_here_to = strtotime('2012-12-10');

$monday = date('m/d/y',strtotime('this week monday', $from_here_to));

echo $monday;
```

Comment: If you change the year month all the time this works